Geoserver Sql view - Viewparams null problem
When using vector tiles, I want to perform operations according to the parameters I created in SQL view.  But geoserver does not see my viewparams values.  Since it sees null, it adds the values ​​I assigned as default.
My openstreet map code.
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });


var gridsetName = 'EPSG:900913';
        var gridNames = ['EPSG:900913:0', 'EPSG:900913:1', 'EPSG:900913:2', 'EPSG:900913:3', 'EPSG:900913:4', 'EPSG:900913:5', 'EPSG:900913:6', 'EPSG:900913:7', 'EPSG:900913:8', 'EPSG:900913:9', 'EPSG:900913:10', 'EPSG:900913:11', 'EPSG:900913:12', 'EPSG:900913:13', 'EPSG:900913:14', 'EPSG:900913:15', 'EPSG:900913:16', 'EPSG:900913:17', 'EPSG:900913:18', 'EPSG:900913:19', 'EPSG:900913:20'];
        var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts';
        var format = 'application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector';
        var infoFormat = 'text/html';
        var layerName = 'Selahattin-test:test-30';
        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:900913',
            units: 'm',
            axisOrientation: 'neu'
        });
        var resolutions = [156543.03390625, 78271.516953125, 39135.7584765625, 19567.87923828125, 9783.939619140625, 4891.9698095703125, 2445.9849047851562, 1222.9924523925781, 611.4962261962891, 305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226, 76.43702827453613, 38.218514137268066, 19.109257068634033, 9.554628534317017, 4.777314267158508, 2.388657133579254, 1.194328566789627, 0.5971642833948135, 0.29858214169740677, 0.14929107084870338];
        params = {
            'REQUEST': 'GetTile',
            'SERVICE': 'WMTS',
            'VERSION': '1.0.0',
            'LAYER': layerName,
            'TILEMATRIX': gridsetName + ':{z}',
            'TILEMATRIXSET': gridsetName,
            'FORMAT': format,
            'TILECOL': '{x}',
            'TILEROW': '{y}',
            'VIEWPARAMS': 'z:{z}' 
        };

        function constructSource() {
            var url = baseUrl + '?'
            for (var param in params) {
                url = url + param + '=' + params[param] + '&';
            }
            url = url.slice(0, -1);

            var source = new ol.source.VectorTile({
                url: url,
                format: new ol.format.MVT({}),
                projection: projection,
                tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                    tileSize: [256, 256],
                    origin: [-2.003750834E7, 2.003750834E7],
                    resolutions: resolutions,
                    matrixIds: gridNames
                }),
                wrapX: true,              
            });
            return source;
        }

        var layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
            source: constructSource()
        });

        var view = new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([39, 40]), // İzmir koordinatları (EPSG:4326 formatında)
          zoom: 9
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [osmLayer, layer],
            target: 'map',
            view: view
        });
      


The requests sent by the client are like this
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=Selahattin-test:test-30&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:9&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector&TILECOL=301&TILEROW=194&VIEWPARAMS=z:9
However, when I look at the geoserver requests, the viewparams value appears to be null.
Request: getMap
        Angle = 0.0
        BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
        Bbox = SRSEnvelope[3835304.3307031244 : 3913575.84765625, 4852834.05109375 : 4931105.568046875]
        BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
        Buffer = 0
        Clip = null
        CQLFilter = null
        Crs = PROJCS["WGS84 / Google Mercator",
  GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST],
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
  PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0],
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0],
  UNIT["m", 1.0],
  AXIS["x", EAST],
  AXIS["y", NORTH],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]
        Elevation = []
        Env = {}
        Exceptions = SE_XML
        FeatureId = null
        FeatureVersion = null
        Filter = null
        Format = application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile
        FormatOptions = {}
        Get = true
        Height = 256
        Interpolations = []
        Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@ff78a1a9]
        MaxFeatures = null
        Palette = null
        RawKvp = {FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile, STYLES=point, WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=256, LAYERS=Selahattin-test:test-30, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:900913, BBOX=3835304.3307031244,4852834.05109375,3913575.84765625,4931105.568046875, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}
        RemoteOwsType = null
        RemoteOwsURL = null
        Request = GetMap
        RequestCharset = UTF-8
        ScaleMethod = null
        Sld = null
        SldBody = null
        SldVersion = null
        SortBy = null
        SortByArrays = null
        SRS = EPSG:900913
        StartIndex = null
        StyleBody = null
        StyleFormat = sld
        Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=point]]
        StyleUrl = null
        StyleVersion = null
        Tiled = false
        TilesOrigin = null
        Time = []
        Transparent = true
        ValidateSchema = false
        Version = 1.1.1
        ViewParams = null
        Width = 256

where am i doing wrong?
